# Accessing UserIdentity from adapter Java code

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-security

I am building a Worklight 6.2 adapter that uses Java.  I am also using authentication through custom login and authenticator Java code by implementing WorkLightAuthLoginModule and WorkLightAuthenticator.  The authentication all works fine.

My adapter code is implemented in the getProtectedAssets static method of class com.myStuff.myClass and is called from the adapter implementation with

```
var returnval = com.myStuff.myClass.getProtectedAssets();
```

getProtectedAssets requires a username and password to connect to a back-end system.  Currently I have those hard-coded in the method for testing, but I need to retrieve them from the Worklight session, presumably through the UserIdentity object I set in my custom login module's createIdentity method.

Is there some way to get access to the user identity from within the adapter Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the WL.Server.getActiveUser() method.
More information about this method can be found here:
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_method_wl_server_getactiveuser.html?lang=en

Comment: Yes, I considered WL.Server.getActiveUser().  That could work, but it is in the JavaScript API, not Java, so I would need to getActiveUser in JavaScript and then pass it into the Java routine.  That's reasonable in this situation but I was hoping there was a way to get at the session data in Java in general.